# How can I manually change the date format of a Pivot Chart?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a Pivot Table that has been used to create a Pivot Chart. The x-axis shows dates, while the y-axis shows the magnitude of the data against each date. The date format being used is "mm/dd/yyyy" - however, when I try to change the format to "dd-mmm", the change doesn't reflect onto the chart. I've tried the following methods with no results:

- Change the date format in the raw data used to create the Pivot Table
- Change the date format in the Pivot Table itself
- Right-click the x-axis labels, select "Format Axis", expand the "Number" format settings, select "Date" in the Category dropdown menu and select "dd-mmm" in the Format dropdown menu
- Create a new Pivot Chart to test if the pre-existing Pivot Chart has some restrictions on changing label formats

Right-clicking the x-axis labels and opening the Field Settings dialog box doesn't help, because it doesn't show the "Number Format" button that many Google-searched tutorials suggest.

Comment: Are you sure your dates are being recognized properly as dates and no as strings? Right click **on the field on the setup of the Pivot Table** and change the format there.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the field in the pivot table containing dates.
[Menu img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5n8U.png)
Select **Field Settings**

Then at the bottom of the pop-up click on **Number Format** button:
[Button img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFeQ3.png)

Then in **Category** select the **Date** and then chose one of the defined visualizations.

Otherwise chose **Custom** in **Category** box and the specify the one you need using **Type** field and letters **d** for day, **m** for month, **y** for year... and so on
[Formatting img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1buPo.png)